# License for feature 'SimpleContactManagement' not found in Kentico

Tags: kentico

Getting this in event log. Looks like Smart search is trying to index Contact objects. I have Search index on Contacts. I have EMS license. 
We are creating/updating contacts using Kentico out of the box Rest api as well.

Any idea, in which case it could happen? could it be user level access issue? or it is something related to License?

````
Description:Cannot obtain object with type om.contact and ID 2317585.
Exception:Message: License for feature 'SimpleContactManagement' not found.
Exception type: CMS.DataEngine.LicenseException
Stack trace:
at CMS.LicenseProvider.LicenseHelperInternal.ReportLicenseError(String redirectUrl, String message)
at CMS.LicenseProvider.LicenseHelper.ReportFailedLicenseCheck(FeatureEnum feature, String domain, Boolean throwError)
at CMS.LicenseProvider.LicenseService.CheckLicense(FeatureEnum feature, String domain, Boolean throwError)
at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`3.GetObjectQuery(Boolean checkLicense)
at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`3.GetInfoByColumn[T](String columnName, T value)
at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`3.GetInfoById(Int32 id, Boolean useHashtable)
at CMS.DataEngine.AbstractInfoProvider`3.CMS.DataEngine.IInfoProvider.GetInfoById(Int32 id)
at CMS.Search.Internal.IndexLogger.LogTaskStart(SearchTaskInfo taskInfo)```
````

Comment: Please, always mention Kentico version and hotfix you are using or confirm you are running latest version + latest hotfix.

Comment: Are you using a custom external class library or web app to create/update the contacts? If that is the case have you initialized the CMS context?

Comment: I created custom module class which updates contacts.. how can initialize CMS context... Just FYI I am using kentico API for it.. if that what you mean by CMS context

Comment: See the following documentation: https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/integrating-3rd-party-systems/using-the-kentico-api-externally I was pointing on the fact that the CMSApplication.Init needs to be called before you use the kentico API in a external application.

Comment: But I think that you aren't using a external application. As you get this error in the event log.

Comment: Oh I see.. No. I am just using in Kentico custom modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure the Contact module/code is installed.  You can check in the Modules application as well as looking in the code files in the following directories:

`/Bin/CMS.Automation.dll`
`/Bin/CMS.ContactManagement.dll`
`/Bin/CMS.OnlineMarketing.dll`
`/CMSModules/Automation`
`/CMSModules/ContactManagement`
`/CMSModules/OnlineMarketing`

If any of those or other EMS features are missing in the database or in the code base, then you'll get those errors.  If this is an existing install and you're just receiving these errors, I'd suggest a few things to try:

1. Restart the website (website and application pool)
2. Rebuild the smart search index(es)
3. If the rebuild fails, check the file system (/App_Data/CMSModules/SmartSearch/) for any .lock files and remove them, then attempt a rebuild.
4. Check the scheduled task which rebuilds or optimizes the indexes isn't set to a non-global admin.
5. Knowing this doesn't appear to be a macro related issue, you could try to resign your macros and see if this helps (probably a last resort though).

Comment: Thanks.. 1st four didn't work.. I think macro re-assignment might help.. will update

Comment: Looks like macro re-assignment solved the issue.. just adding here if anyone else run into the issue